# Concrete5 banned admin

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

Guy who's managing content on a site send me [this screenshot](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/0001/2051/108547/160220/7104a4066f.png). It says that he's IP was blocked. But I don't see any bans in admin panel ([screenshot](http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0001/2051/108547/160220/82feb17e47.png)).

Also I just noticed that if I change a language of a system on this path:
`/dashboard/system/basics/multilingual`
it doesn't change it even after re-log in. Something's not right here...

Answer (score 0):

you can see from your settings that IP bans only last 10 minutes. Your admin may have been banned and then un-banned after 10 minutes so you wouldn't see it in the list.

Best option is to ask him to try again.